# How to list the files on a tape with tar?

Tags: unix, tar, tape, hp-ux

On a HP-UX OS I have a backup on a magnetic tape created from the SAM.
Everywhere I read the instructions to list-verify the contents of the tape is to use the **TAR** program:

```
#tar tvf /dev/rmt/[tapefile]
```

I've created a new directory **/tape** with 777 permissions, but when I execute the above command it gives me an error message:

```
#pwd
/tape
#tar tvf /dev/rmt/0mn >> listtape
Tar: blocksize = 2
directory checksum error
```

Going after the blocksize error I used another version of the command with the **"b"** flag:

```
#tar tvb 2 /dev/rmt/0mn >> listtape
directory checksum error
```

**Anybody have a sugestion? How can I view the contents of the tape? What does this error means?**

Comment: Are you sure you have a tar style backup on the tape?  Do you know what command was used to make the archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did solved this problem and I will post the answer here just in case anyone else have a similar problem.

Since the backup was created using SAM, TAR was NOT used to create the tape.  More than likely **'fbackup'** was actually used.

In order to see what is on the tape i should use the **'frecover'** program.

**This command will read the table of contents from the tape (/dev/rmt/0m) and write it out to /tape/tape.idx.**

```
# frecover -I /tape/tape.idx -f /dev/rmt/0m
```

Answer (score 2):

To see what format a backup is in you can use something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/rmt/0m of=/tmp/tapehead bs=1024 count=2
file /tmp/tapehead
```

I.e copy the first 2k from the tape to `/tmp/tapehead` and then run file on it to see what format it is.

This assumes that your `/etc/magic` file contains the given format description but even if not so, you might be able to identify the format using more, vi or od combined with Google. Some backup programs (Amanda for example) even includes a text file as the first file on the tape describing how to extract the tape.

Answer (score 0):

`tar tv` should be sufficient to list the files to stdout (unless there's more than one tape device).

Comment: Just "tar tv"? :o

Comment: There it is again the same error...
`#tar tv`
`Tar: blocksize = 2`
`directory checksum error`

Comment: Something ain't right... time to call HP I think.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i don't know if your solved your problem. But if i remember i faced already this problem.

Try to rewind the tape

`mt -f /dev/rmt/0mn rewind`

and launch after this command

`/usr/local/bin/tar tv /dev/rmt/0mn`

The problem is the difference version of tar tool that is used to create the archive with your tar tool.

try this :

`which tar`

hope this helped you.

Comment: Just tried that. There is only one tar on the system that is `/usr/bin/tar`. I also rewind the tape as you suggested it still gives the same error. :S I even tryed to forward it on the first file using `# mt -t /dev/rmt/0mn fsf 1`.

Comment: Is a notsense to rewind a non rewind tape? on 0mn n near "norewind"